# How to monitor Outlook mail received event from .NET

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a requirement to write an application which will allow users to run selected scripts when a mail with a certain subject is received from a certain address. Basically the application should monitor mail arriving in the outlook (Exchange server 2007). How can it be done? Any idea would be helpful.

Basically, I need to keep track of the New Mail event and retrieve the sender and mail subject details to my .NET application.

[To be implemented in .NET]

Answer (score 2):

That can be accomplished by using the Outlook ObjectModel and the MailItem/Item Object and events or by just checking the MailItems for **Unread** Emails using a timer. check the MSDN for details about the [Object(MailItem)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946(office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Never did it before, but as far as i know, this can be done by writing your own outlook add-in.

Some source which would maybe helpful:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx
- http://www.outlookcode.com

Answer (score 0):

Also if you don't want to use outlook i.e stand alone you can use EWS or WebDav directly against the Exchange Server. Both have notification services.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, and i can say that Olivier is pointing you in the right direction. In addition, if you are using Outlook 2003 as your client, you might want to have a look at the Redemption library as that will get rid of all the annoying "security" prompts that require user intervention.